# Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php on line 651

Tags: upgrade

Combined a Magento 1.9.0. database with a Magento 1.9.4.1. basic installation and get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function **setData()** on boolean in `/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php` on **line 651**

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code for reference?

Comment: Thank you so much writing me. The code in  Config.php is

Comment: at Line 651:        $attribute = Mage::getModel($model)->setData($attributeData);

Comment: magefms.. is it actually possible to connect an old database with a new shop ? I am looking a way to easy reset the magento version.

Comment: yeah just make sure the old database supports the same Magento version of your new shop

Comment: And how can i find out and make the needed changes ?

Comment: It is not the same version. The current is 1.9.0 and I want to upgrade to 1.9.4.